# R Programming other alternatives for plot

Tags: r

I wonder how you can simplify these two :

```
plot (payroll,wins)
id = identify(payroll, wins,labels = code, n = 5)
plot (payroll,wins)
with(data, text(payroll, wins, labels = code, pos = 1, cex=0.5))
```

using other alternatives - pch() dan as.numeric()?

Comment: You're not using the `id` at all. Perhaps explain in words what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there any way to get the same result using as.numeric() - perhaps slightly different since you can alter the icon using pch() but I do not understand how to use as.numeric() ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. Plot, identify points, plot those points? The code makes little sense to me. Can you provide a reproducible example and exactly tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there anyway to use as.numeric into plot ?  The main point is I have to use as.numeric to achieve the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's easier but you change pch during identification as below (taken from the R-help). Every time you click empty point change to filled-in dot.

```
# data simulation
data <- data.frame(payroll = rnorm(10), wins = rnorm(10), code = letters[1:10])

identifyPch <- function(x, y = NULL, n = length(x), plot = FALSE, pch = 19, ...)
{
  xy <- xy.coords(x, y)
  x <- xy$x
  y <- xy$y
  sel <- rep(FALSE, length(x))
  while (sum(sel) < n) {
    ans <- identify(x[!sel], y[!sel], labels = which(!sel), n = 1, plot = plot, ...)
    if(!length(ans)) {
      break
    }
    ans <- which(!sel)[ans]
    points(x[ans], y[ans], pch = pch)
    sel[ans] <- TRUE
  }
  ## return indices of selected points
  which(sel)
}

if(dev.interactive()) { ## use it
  with(data, plot(payroll,wins))

  id = with(data, identifyPch(payroll, wins))
}
```